# map one class to many classes with type/item

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate-mapping

My problem is that i have parent classes, and for each of the parents i have list of classB.
for example, the tables are:

Images

```
id
type
item
filename
```

computers

```
id
owner
age
```

workers

```
id
name
age
```

we have many images for every computer and worker. in the classes of computer and worker we have list of images. for the computers the image items are:

```
id=auto generate
type=1
item= id of computer
```

for the workers the image items are:

```
id=auto generate
type=2
item=id of worker
```

The classes should be:
Computers:
-id
-age
-owner
-images
Workers:
-id
-age
-name
-images

About the image, i dont sure what do i need but something like that:
-id
-filename
(optional, if it needed by the mapping)
-type
-item

some idea how to map that?

Comment: Try with NHibernate any type mapping http://ayende.com/blog/3966/nhibernate-mapping-any

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class ComputerMap : ClassMap<Computer>
{
    public ComputerMap()
    {
        HasMany(x => x.Images)
            .Where("type = 1")
            .KeyColumn("item")
            .Inverse()
            .Cascade.All();
    }
}

class WorkerMap : ClassMap<Worker>
{
    public WorkerMap()
    {
        HasMany(x => x.Images)
            .Where("type = 2")
            .KeyColumn("item")
            .Inverse()
            .Cascade.All();
    }
}

class ImageMap : ClassMap<Image>
{
    public WorkerMap()
    {
        ReferencesAny(x => x.Item)
            .EntityIdentifierColumn("item")
            .EntityTypeColumn("type")
            .AddMetaValue<Computer>(1)
            .AddMetaValue<Worker>(2)
            .IdentityType<int>();     <-- maybe optional
    }
}

// in Computer and Worker have this
public void AddImage(Image image)
{
    this.Images.Add(image);
    image.Item = this
}
```

Comment: But this is the problem.
in the first stage i append image to the db, and after that, by the id of the images, i append the images to the worker and insert the worker to the db.
the image (in the db) is not update when i do that.

Comment: ok then you want cascading, see update. i also added inverse, which is sane here

Comment: I sent message about that this is not working but now i see that it is not the type.
The worker updateing the images but with wrong type.
every time the type is 1, also if it not have any meta value equals to 1.

Comment: maybe the default value for the column?

Comment: This is not the default value of the column on the db.

Comment: i understood what was the problem. the problem was that the class didnt derived from the WithImage interface.